# Get the First Value from array of checked checkboxes

Tags: php, html

```
<input type="checkbox" name="cats[]" id="8" value=" as">    
<input type="checkbox" name="cats[]" id="9" value="222">    
<input type="checkbox" name="cats[]" id="3" value="as">
<input type="checkbox" name="cats[]" id="6" value="dsd">
```

Above are checkboxes 
 
I got these checked values from $_POST['cats']
Now i want first value of $_POST['cats'] array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply select the first element:

```
echo $_POST['cats'][0]
```

Be aware though, that only boxes that are CHECKED will be submitted by the post.

That means if you have four checkboxes in your original page, but the user only checks one, only ONE will be submitted.

To understand this further, you should look into multi-dimensional arrays. That is what this is, the first element of the array is selected by the name (in your case `['cats']`) and then by an index - which defines the offset for this specific element.

Edit: To add further detail to the answer for non-numeric arrays

If your array (unlike a checkbox) has named elements, you can use array_keys to then access them via a numeric value (ie, `0` for the first element)

```
$array=array( 'First' => 'One', 'Second' => 'Two', 'Third' => 'Three');
$keys=array_keys($array);
echo $array[$keys[0]];

// Output One
```

Comment: @Monika You can also always use a `print_r($yourArray);` to get a better understanding of what it is and how you can access it - for example to see that it is a 2D array, not a 1D array).